# IntelliJ Idea take a long time to start (JetBrains CertificateException)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, certificate, jetbrains-ide

My IntelliJ take a long time to start. 
So when I check the starting log, I can see that they're issues with the jetbrains certificates :

```
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative DNS name matching www.jetbrains.com found.
```

and

```
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative DNS name matching plugins.jetbrains.com found.
```

The slowness could be link at those certificates issues ? How could I fix them?

Comment: Have you asked jetbrains directly? Is this on Windows or Linux?

Comment: What OS do you use? Please submit a ticket at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/requests/new with the [idea.log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241085) and the [thread dumps](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544899) attached.

Comment: On windows. I just made a ticket on the intellij support. As soon as I have update for them then I'll update this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated my Intellij and I moved the installation into "program files x86" (instead of "program files") and now it's better. Like suggested the jetbrains helpdesk, it's most likely an IO issue on my PC. Maybe I can also move my settings folder from the usual place to a faster IO place on my hard disk (currently slow because there some backups system on the home).

Comment: How does moving from Program Files to Program Files x86 could fix this issue? Can I put the installation in another folder?